# Better Way to do query with database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

1st:  Is there any better way to do

```
sqlcommand object = new sqlcommand("insert into sometable values '" + textboxes.texts "'," + somelabelvalues.text + "')" , connectiondb); //true for update,delete and everything inwhich we want to feed input data into database.
```

This is not safe. Is there any better way to do this because this was taught in our C# class.

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You're looking for the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723)

Comment: Change your terminology.  This is not "the traditional way" to access data.  Look up something called "SQL Injection" and you'll find that this is the "traditional way" to expose your database to anybody who wants to modify it.  Beyond that, look up "parameterized queries" and "ORMs" to find more traditional ways of accessing databases.

Comment: It's not safe since you are inviting for sql-injection by concatenating strings. Use sql-parammeters... always.

Comment: @SikanderHayyat: Yes, that's a *huge* step in the right direction.  And one that involves the least amount of refactoring and learning new technologies.  Essentially the point is that your method treats user input as *executable code* which is very, very dangerous.  Using query parameters treats user input as only data, which is what it should be.

Comment: Well @David I really appreciate your help. Thats All I want to Know. Thanks Mate!!!
Hcore I watched the video there. That is good. and Am planning to watch the rest.
tim Thanks I'll learn it!!!

There is one more thing, If injection is there then how do I avoid this. Well in PHP We use real_escape_string etc. to sort this commands.

Comment: @SikanderHayyat read your answers, they all describe how to avoid injection...

Comment: Thanks man
Now I understand it completly :D

Answer (score 5):

Use a `SqlParameter`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from sometable where value = @value");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "value");
```

Answer (score 2):

Cam Bruce is correct, use `SqlParameter` always.  However, I would like to expound on that just a bit.

First of all, you asked if there is "a better way to do this", the answer is Yes - Use parameters.  There is another answer however that was addressed in the original comments, there is a *different way to do this* using Entity Framework.  I would say that it's only better in certain situations.  If this is your only SQL query in the project, then good lord please do not use Entity Framework as the overhead would be unnecessary.

You can read up on  [Entity Framework on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

You should also definitely read up on [SQL Injection Attacks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Now on to your code.  As Cam stated above, use `SqlParameter`.  He did leave out a couple good practices though on properly handing your command and connection.

It is a good practice to wrap both your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` in `using` statements so that when you are finished with the objects, they will be disposed of.

```
string mySqlCommandText = "INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3)";    

//Wrap your connection/command in using blocks
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(mySqlConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(mySqlCommandText, conn))
{
    //Add your values to the parameters
    //This is how you avoid the SQL Injection attack
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", myValue1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", myValue2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value3", myValue3);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }  //The cmd and conn objects are disposed of here as they are now out of scope.
```

Comment: Bravo bravo!!
You answered everything!!!
Thankyou very very much!!!

Comment: @sikanderhayyat the way to thank the poster for such a good answer is by pressing the up arrow button at the left

Comment: @HighCore Thanks mate ;)  He did end up accepting the answer so I didn't want to press the issue hehe

Answer (score 0):

Yes this way is not safe because of [SQLInjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability... 
as `Cam Bruce` said, you can use command parameters to make it safe and secure...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from sometable where value = @value");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "value");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

just that!